# Multiple underlying brownian motions

Tags: brownian-motion

I'm trying to find a way to price a triple product forward with payoff X*Y*Z at time T using risk-neutral pricing.
But I don't really have a math background and I have trouble finding a way to account for correlation with 3 assets.

I know that for 2 assets with SDEs:

dX= a1dt + b1dz1

dY = a2dt + b2dz2

We have:

[image]

But how could we translate this expression when we have 3 assets instead of 2?

I looked for it online but examples were always given with 2 assets.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) of the covariance matrix.

For a symmetric matrix $\Sigma$, the Cholesky matrix $L$ has the property

$$
\Sigma = LL^T
$$
where $L$ is a matrix with zeros above the main diagonal.

In your case,

$$
d\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\\Z\end{pmatrix}=\ldots + Ldz
$$
where $L$ is the lower Cholesky matrix.

You can find a general $3x3$ example at [Rosetta code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) and a $3x3$ online   [calculator at Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=6fdbffcb9af3d886e01de25da845e91e)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it :)